# Angular 2 DateTime Picker Issue

Tags: angular

I'm wondering if anyone has had this issue before? I'm using the Angular 2 DateTime picker (https://cuppalabs.github.io/angular2-datetimepicker/#/datetimepicker). I have the DateTime picker inside a form and when I go to choose a time and set it, the form is being submitted for some reason. The form is attached to ngSubmit, but I am not submitting the form?

```
  // Inside form
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="farm-harvest">Harvest</label>
    <angular2-date-picker class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="date" formControlName="farmHarvest" [settings]="settings"></angular2-date-picker>
  </div>

  // Default options being set
  date: Date = new Date();
   settings = {
   bigBanner: true,
   timePicker: true,
   format: 'medium',
   defaultOpen: false
  };
```

Comment: a minimal working example on stackblitz will help... to quote my personal experience: many a time, when i try to replicate a single issue in its minimal form, the issue becomes clear

Comment: 'Set Time' button has no specific type, hence, it is 'submit' by default. Please contact the developer of that component or you customize it yourself.

Comment: Can you clarify how you found that out please wannadream, been looking at this for a while now. Thanks

Comment: https://unsee.cc/3de1c623/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple solution that should work.

Instead on ngSubmit method in form, remove it and add the method on click of the submit button.

Answer (score 0):

Please add  ngNativeValidate  in your form tag